# Android - Eclipse: Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java, android, arrays, asynchronous, download

I'm still learning and I've tried to figure this out and I figured I'd ask the experts. Any ideas?

I get the error on this line:
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById ([btnIds]);

```
public class choiceTest extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.atcchoice);
}
final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v){ 
         switch(v.getId()){  
         case R.id.sec1:  
            break; 
         case R.id.sec2: 
            break; 
         case R.id.sec3: 
            break; 
         } 
     } 
};
final int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.sec1, R.id.sec2, R.id.sec3};{ 
for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) { 
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById ([btnIds]); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener); 
}



}
}
```

Also, this is for a downloader program and I am using Async to download my files.  What could I add to the above code to change my downloader URL to a different one?  Otherwise I will have a very long code...  Here is how download URL code.

```
private void startDownload() {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute("http://www.website.com/document.pdf");

}
```

The async code to download it:

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access an array like this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById( btnIds[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

your are passing whole array.
change it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) { 
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById ([btnIds]); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener); 
}
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) { 
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById (btnIds[i]); 
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener); 
}
```